# Count occurrence of an element in Haskell list and return max sequence

Tags: list, haskell

I have the following code to count the occurrence of an element in a Haskell list:

```
data Elem = Vanilla | Choco deriving (Eq,Show)
maxStarSeq :: [Elem] -> Int
maxStarSeq [] = 0
maxStarSeq (Vanilla:xs) = 0 + maxStarSeq xs
maxStarSeq (Choco:xs) = 1 + maxStarSeq xs
```

Now, how can I return the max sequence of that element, instead of an absolute counter? I mean, let's say that my list is:

```
[Vanilla,Choco,Choco,Vanilla,Choco]
```

With my code, I will get 3 because there are 3 Choco characters in the list. What I want is to get 2, because that is the max sequence of Choco characters, while the next sequence is shorter.

What I need is some way to make a comparison between the sequences, to evaluate which is longer, or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [worker wrapper](https://wiki.haskell.org/Worker_wrapper) pattern to achieve your required result:

```
maxStarSeq :: [Elem] -> Int
maxStarSeq xs = aux xs 0 0
    where aux [] acc prev = max acc prev
          aux (Vanilla:xs) acc prev = aux xs (max acc prev) 0
          aux (Choco:xs) acc prev = aux xs acc (prev + 1)
```

The `prev` parameter will track the current number of consecutive `Choco` parameters. The `acc` parameter will have the maximum number of `Choco` parameters for it's previous run. It's value will be updated each time you encounter `Vanilla` value.

Comment: I'm trying to apply this, but the compiler give me an error in the semi-last row: parse error on input aux

Comment: @BranStark Most likely an indentation problem in your source. Make sure all the "aux" are vertically aligned.

Comment: All of them vertically aligned and still getting this error. What am I missing?

Comment: @BranStark You are most probably missing tab and spaces.  Use space for indenting.

Comment: could you please give me an example of correct indentation in this precise case? Sorry, first week using Haskell.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `group` and `maximum`

```
import Data.List
maxSeqLength :: Eq a => [a] -> Int
maxSeqLength [] = 0
maxSeqLength xs = (maximum . map length . group) xs
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there another way to do it, just using pattern matching?

Comment: @BranStark What do you mean? This solution does use pattern matching.