# Recursion in Haskell: support functions

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have another problem with the first exercises in Haskell.
To understand the recursion of this paradigm I would like to solve this problem:

Given a list of items Elem defined as follows:

```
data Elem = Star | War
```

computes the length of the longest sequence of "War"

```
maxWarSeq :: [Elem] -> Int

maxWarSeq [] = 0
maxWarSeq (Star:xs) = 1 + maxWarSeq xs
maxWarSeq (War:xs) = maxWarSeq xs
```

This way I count sequences total, but I have no idea how you count only "the longest".
With a support function I could solve the problem but I need help.

Example of list:

```
testElem = [Star, War, War, Star, Star, War, War, War, Star, Star, War]
```

the result should be "3".

Can you help me please?

Comment: This is almost exactly the same question as [Count occurrence of an element in Haskell list and return max sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141786/count-occurrence-of-an-element-in-haskell-list-and-return-max-sequence), which was asked (and answered) earlier today.

Comment: One way to solve approach this problem would be to realize that you might want to know how long the current sequence of `War`s is as well as how long the longest sequence you've found is.

Comment: Another approach to the problem would be to break the list up into its `War` sequences (or their lengths) and then find the longest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing recursion you have to think about the variables you are going to need in each call of the program to carry on the "state". In this case in order to see the maximum sequence you need to "carry" the current maximum and the global maximum. Then at the end a sequence you should decide whether you have a new maximum or not. I have implemented a solution to that using a helper function:

```
data Elem = Star | War
testElem = [Star, War, War, Star, Star, War, War, War, Star, Star, War]

maxWarSeq_hlp :: Int -> Int -> [Elem] -> Int
maxWarSeq_hlp curmax prevmax [] = max curmax prevmax
maxWarSeq_hlp curmax prevmax (War:xs) = maxWarSeq_hlp (curmax+1) prevmax xs
maxWarSeq_hlp curmax prevmax (Star:xs) = maxWarSeq_hlp 0 (max curmax prevmax) xs

maxWarSeq :: [Elem] -> Int
maxWarSeq list = maxWarSeq_hlp 0 0 list
```

Basically I start with *curmax* and *prevmax* being 0 and then I add 1 to *curmax* every time I see **War** and every time I see **Star** I reset the *curmax* count to zero and set *prevmax* to the maximum of *curmax* and *prevmax*