# Count occurrence of any element in Haskell list and return max sequence using worker pattern

Tags: haskell

As a follow-up question to [Count occurrence of an element in Haskell list and return max sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29141786/3320256) I
played around with one of the [given solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29142841/3320256) 
and came up with an extension to the original question:
would it be possible to determine the longest sequence
of any be it either `Vanilla` or `Choco` whatsoever `Elem` using the
[worker pattern](https://wiki.haskell.org/Worker_wrapper).

The only possibility I could come up so far is for the given two Elem data types but what I am interested in is one for arbitrary number of different types (in the example i. e. `Strawberries` etc).

```
data Elem = Vanilla | Choco deriving (Eq, Show)
maxStarSeq :: [Elem] -> Int
maxStarSeq xs = aux xs 0 0 0 0
    where aux [] acc prev bcc prev2 = max acc $ max prev $ max bcc prev2
          aux (Vanilla:xs) acc prev bcc prev2 = aux xs (max acc prev) 0 bcc (prev2 + 1)
          aux (Choco:xs) acc prev bcc prev2 = aux xs acc (prev + 1) (max bcc prev2) 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generalize the function to work on any type that supports equality testing (is an instance of `Eq`) and thus you don't have to worry about the number of different constructors.

```
maxSeq :: Eq a => [a] -> Int
maxSeq [] = 0
maxSeq (x:xs) = go 1 1 x xs where
    go longest current _ [] = max longest current
    go longest current prev (x:xs)
        | x == prev = go longest (current + 1) prev xs
        | otherwise = go (max longest current) 1 x xs
```

The `longest` parameter keeps track of the longest sequence we've encountered so far (regardless of value), `current` holds the length of the current sequence and `prev` is the value of the previous element so that we can check if the current sequence continues or not.

However, the recommended approach is not to use a worker function but to compose existing standard library functionality:

```
import Data.List (group)

maxSeq :: Eq a => [a] -> Int
maxSeq = maximum . map length . group
```

This groups sequential elements based on equality, calculates the length of each group and the picks the maximum length.